# PHP curl CURLOPT_RESOLVE not working

Tags: php, curl

I have example.com on two different servers, I use php curl to connect to one server, do some tasks and then try to connect to another server and do some other tasks, but it doesn't obey the CURLOPT_RESOLVE second time as you can see in the verbose output.

I tried CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT set to 0 but still connects to old ip.

Any idea how i can fix it?

I can not connect to ip's directly unfortunately.

```
* Added example.com:80:207.230.220.255 to DNS cache
* Hostname was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 207.97.92.288...
* Connected to example.com (207.97.92.288) port 80 (#0)
> GET /example.php HTTP/1.1

Host: example.com

Accept: */*



< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

< Date: Tue, 05 Apr 2016 18:00:58 GMT

* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache

< Accept-Ranges: bytes

< Transfer-Encoding: chunked

< Content-Type: text/html

< 

* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
```

EDIT *******

Added code :

```
$check_ping_resolve = ["example.com:80:207.230.220.255"];

$check_ping = "http://example.com/123.php";

$check_ping_verbose = fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . '/ping.txt', 'w');

$check_ping_curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($check_ping_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($check_ping_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($check_ping_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($check_ping_curl, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($check_ping_curl, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, $check_ping_resolve);
curl_setopt($check_ping_curl, CURLOPT_URL, $check_ping);
curl_setopt($check_ping_curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($check_ping_curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $check_ping_verbose);

$check_ping_curl_result = curl_exec($check_ping_curl);
```

Comment: post the code.....

Comment: @Pamblam added code, code before that would be same but different ip.

Comment: According to http://php.net/curl_setopt `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` expects an array.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, I solved it by adding this option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [official documentation](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_RESOLVE.html) for the `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` option:

> Remove names from the DNS cache again, to stop providing these fake resolves, by including a string in the linked list that uses the format "-HOST:PORT". The host name must be prefixed with a dash, and the host name and port number must exactly match what was already added previously.

So when you send a request to the second server you have to remove mapping for the previously used server IP address as well:

```
$check_ping_resolve = [
    '-example.com:80:207.97.92.288',
    'example.com:80:207.230.220.255'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!defined(CURLOPT_RESOLVE)) {
    define('CURLOPT_RESOLVE', 10203);
}
$check_ping_verbose = fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . '/ping.txt', 'w');
$gateway_port = '443';
$gateway_ip = '1.1.1.1';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, array('example.com:' . $gateway_port . ':' . $gateway_ip));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $check_ping_verbose);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result; echo "1";
```

thanks https://gist.github.com/davidstrauss/64c4ee41ff81279c96ce

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.